# Strange behaviour when getting IP address via DHCP from wifi access point

Tags: wifi, dhcp, ipv6, internet, lubuntu

I'm experiencing a strange behaviour with wifi connection on Lubuntu. Basically, Lubuntu is getting only an IPv6 address when connecting to certain access point, although it should be getting an IPv4 address too.

The scenario is the following:

- Two wifi access points for different networks. Both of them providing IP addresses via DHCP. Call them **A** and **B**.
- A laptop with Fedora 31 and Intel wireless adapter (call if    **F**).
- A laptop with Lubuntu 20.04 and Realtek wireless adapter (call it **L**).

This is what happens:

1. Both **F** and **L** get IPv4 and IPv6 addresses when connecting to **A**. Everything works OK.
2. If **F** connects to **B** it gets IPv4 and IPv6 addresses. Everything works OK.
3. If **L** connects to **B** it gets only an IPv6 address. **L** cannot visit
   some domains (e.g. google.com works but amazon.com is not
   working).
4. If **L** renews the DHCP lease (doing `sudo dhclient wlo1`) when connected to **B**, then it does get IPv4 and IPv6 addresses
   and everything works OK.

Some comments:

- The Realtek wireless adapter of **L** was not working properly after a fresh
  install of Lubuntu. So I installed the driver provided by the package
  `rtl8821ce-dkms`.
- The problem is what happens when **L** connects to **B** (described in 3 and 4).
- The behaviour described in 1 and 2 is provided for comparison purposes only.

---

**My questions**

Why is this? How could I force **L** to get both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses from the start when connecting to **B**?

Comment: Don't know, but I would power up the laptop and run tcpdump and capture what is going out on the line, since you have no idea whether the problem is local or remote. You may have to put it into a tight loop to grab the info.

Comment: @Bib Can the problem be remote? Note that laptop **F** works OK and **L** works OK too after running `sudo dhclient wlo1`.

Comment: Given what happens, I would not rule anything out. A number of pieces of info you have not given, is what and where are the DHCP servers? Whether there is a single one, multiple ones or if both routers are acting as servers, or whether both routers are in the same domain, different building etc?

Comment: @Bib Both are routers working also as DHCP servers. Both of them were provided by local ISPs for accessing ADSL services. They are on the same building, 2 meters apart. Each one of them is the unique DHCP server on its network.

Comment: You have told a tale remarkably free of information we could use to think about your problem. No software version numbers, no configuration files, no logs, no packet dumps, nothing but people talk. Read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask .

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add new information, properly formatted. Information added via comments is hard for you to format, hard for us to read and ignored by future readers. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our uplink to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]